# How to test component's resize behaviour

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm using Jest as the testing framework. I'm trying to test a function inside the ResizeObserver callback.

```
import ResizeObserver from 'resize-observer-polyfill';

const fn = jest.fn();
const element = document.createElement('div');

document.body.appendChild(element);
new ResizeObserver(() => {
  fn();
}).observe(element);
```

In my test, I tried to change the width and height of `element` using the style property to make the `ResizeObserver` to trigger

```
it('should call the fn function', () => {
  element.style.width = '100px';
  element.style.height = '200px';

  expect(fn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
});
```

But didn't work. Here's the test error

`Expected mock function to have been called two times, but it was called zero times.`

What do I need to do to simulate the `ResizeObserver` callback? Please help.

**Note:** The code above is an only simplified version.

Comment: Why would you want to test that, isn't it the job for the `resize-observer-polyfill` maintainers to do so?

Comment: I'm creating a resizable component so i want to test if it is responding when it gets resized and also test what its new state after resized.

Comment: Well as a rule of thumb i don't think you should test the behavior of 3rd party libraries, the same reason you are not testing if react really renders something to the `DOM` or a `div` is really fixed positioned when you define it to be. maybe what you really want to test is what your code does when the element is in `x` size or `y` size. just set the size and check if your code runs as expected, just "trust" the `ResizeObserver`  to notify you for the size change

Comment: Yes you're right. Thanks for that advice but i'm not sure if that rule fits for my case. I want to test my component`s own behaviour when it's resized.